# Error while connecting to ClearCase(CCRC) via STS eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, clearcase

Getting below error in the log while connecting to ClearCase(CCRC) via STS eclipse.

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.6.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201410091308
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)

ClearCase
Version: 7.1.0.10


Error 


!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2015-02-05 10:25:39.807
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception during blocked modal context.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.block(ModalContext.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:527)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.util.CcProviderFactory$2.run(CcProviderFactory.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.util.CcProviderFactory.showLoginDialog(CcProviderFactory.java:658)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.util.CcProviderFactory.eventFired(CcProviderFactory.java:361)
    at com.ibm.rational.team.client.rpm.events.GUIEventDispatcher.fireEvent(GUIEventDispatcher.java:48)
    at com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.actions.ConnectAction.run(ConnectAction.java:91)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.wizards.joinProject.ServerComponent.onConnect(ServerComponent.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.component.renderer.WidgetRenderer$1.widgetSelected(WidgetRenderer.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.wizards.joinProject.ViewWizard.run(ViewWizard.java:94)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.CreateViewAction.run(CreateViewAction.java:63)
    at com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.actions.GIWorkbenchActionDelegate.run(GIWorkbenchActionDelegate.java:76)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.actions.CCWorkbenchActionDelegate.run(CCWorkbenchActionDelegate.java:73)
    at com.ibm.rational.team.client.ui.actions.GIActionDelegate.runWithEvent(GIActionDelegate.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.toolbar.activities.ActivitiesToolbar.getCoolbarManager(ActivitiesToolbar.java:547)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.toolbar.activities.ActivitiesToolbar.getActivitiesToolbarManager(ActivitiesToolbar.java:564)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.toolbar.activities.ActivitiesToolbar.activitiesToolbarShouldBeShown(ActivitiesToolbar.java:332)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.toolbar.activities.ActivitiesToolbar.updateToolbarForComboBox(ActivitiesToolbar.java:392)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.toolbar.activities.ActivitiesToolbar.setCurrentWorkspaceContext(ActivitiesToolbar.java:128)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.toolbar.activities.ActivitiesToolbar$3.eventFired(ActivitiesToolbar.java:308)
    at com.ibm.rational.team.client.rpm.events.GUIEventDispatcher.fireEvent(GUIEventDispatcher.java:48)
    at com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ui.util.CcProviderFactory$10.run(CcProviderFactory.java:2119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    ... 64 more
```

Comment: Starting eclipse with -clean option or deleting .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\*.s* file didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could indicate an incompatibility between the CCRC eclipse plugin 3.6.2 and the recent Eclipse Luna 4.4.

Check if you can install/run that same plugin with an older Eclipse, one listed in "[System Requirements for the ClearCase Remote Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21224586)"